# get_terms(); show private posts when logged in

Tags: terms, post-status, private

Hi have a  custom post type "FAQ".
I got some "FAQ's" that are private, also only visible for logged in users.

I used "get_terms()" funktion for a widget that is listing links to the categories of those "FAQ's".

The "get_terms" does not list the terms, that have only private "FAQ's".

```
$taxonomy = 'faq_kategorien';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
    echo  '<li><a href="/faq_kategorien/'.$tax_term->slug.'">'.$tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
}
```

How can i get those terms that include only "private" posts ?

Comment: This could be very helpful:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39413/how-to-get-all-posts-but-the-private-ones

Comment: My first guess would be `get_terms($taxonomy, array('hide_empty'=>false));`, but it might be more complex than that.

Answer (score -2):

We had the same issue in one of our projects and we find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999933/wordpress-displays-private-posts-to-logged-in-users-how-to-turn-this-function)

[This other](http://wpengineer.com/1906/display-private-posts-to-logged-in-users/) doesn't work in our case, but maybe is a second option for you.